# What sort of seed pod is this?

Tags: species-identification, botany, entomology, trees, seeds

My son found this floating in a stream in Massachusetts, in the northeastern US. It was intact when he found it, but he cracked it open to see what was inside. I did some Google image searching, but couldn't find anything. Any idea what it is, and where it came from?

[image: whole pod]

[image: insides]

Comment: Are there any trace of a hole through which a bug could have entered? The content looks messy. Can you isolate seed ?

Comment: @bli no, there weren't any holes in it. I haven't dug around in it, but I can take a look for seeds when I get home from work.

Comment: Looks like a gall such as an [oak gall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oak_apple).

Comment: Looks like a gall. was it delicate and lightweight? If so I'd guess it belongs to the [oak apple gall wasp](http://www.fcps.edu/islandcreekes/ecology/oak_apple_gall_wasp.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually not a seed pod, but rather a [gall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gall) (see [here](http://www.bio.brandeis.edu/fieldbio/galls/galls.html) or [here](http://www.extension.umn.edu/garden/insects/find/insect-and-mite-galls/) for more info about galls). Specifically, it most likely is a gall belonging to the **Oak Apple Gall Wasp (*Amphibolips confluenta*)**. You can read about this species and its gall [here](http://www.fcps.edu/islandcreekes/ecology/oak_apple_gall_wasp.htm).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, it was quite light for its size, and I suppose "delicate" could be used, but it was certainly difficult to cut open :)