# Can anyone identify this creature that looks like a stick?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image][image][image]
This thing was on me. I thought was a stick until it moved. It had a black worm like thing come out one end and stood up and thats how it moved. It would stick to fabric also. In Louisiana

Comment: Looks like a terrestrial Caddisfly, the order of *Trichoptera*. Please add the location (country) were you found it, we might be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a Caddisfly (Trichoptera). Though my guess is a moth (Lepidoptera). Specifically one of the Psychidae family, also known as "bagworm moths." They are common pests in most parts of the world and while they're typically seen fixed in place they spend much of their life mobile. Both of these groups spin a case from silk and attach detritus to the outside so without a better look at the resident insect it is basically impossible to distinguish them from a photograph. However, as a general rule (with some exceptions), Caddisfly larva tend to be aquatic.
Here are a couple of links to descriptions of the groups (with pictures!) as they appear on BugGuide:
[Psychidae](https://bugguide.net/node/view/122)

[Trichoptera](https://bugguide.net/node/view/5233)

Comment: Hi David, and welcome to Biology.SE. Answers in general should include supporting reference(s). Species identification answers in particular are best with a representative picture of the species for comparison as well. For a good example of how to answer a species-identification question, see [these](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/42116/43480) [answers](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/42520/43480) by @theforestecologist

Comment: Knowing the location, I think you are right this is a bagworm. In North America there is only one terrestrial Trichoptera and that species looks different.

Comment: @David. Welcome to Bio.SE! As De Novo mentioned, please add some support (preferably from a reputable source!) to strengthen your answer. I agree that this is likely a bagworm (see previous posts on the subject [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/51252/16866) and [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/73100/16866)). It's *very* unlikely to be a trichopteran larvae outside of an aquatic setting.

Answer (score -1):

This is a clothing moth.  Casebearing clothing moth. The larvae wraps itself in a fabric or cotton like cocoon and feeds on soiled clothing or anything made from animals. The worm like larvae will emerge from the cocoon

Comment: Welcome user70847. This answer could be improved by the addition of one or two references, even a picture showing the clothing moth - as answers here are expected to explain why they are correct and be supported by references where possible. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for our guidelines. Enjoy the site.